# Create a public key on a Heroku server

Tags: heroku, public-key

I'd like to have a public key on a Heroku server. I run

```
$ heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.2575
~ $ ssh-keygen -t rsa
~ $ ls .ssh/
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub
```

Everything is okay now. But when I rerun `heroku run bash` the `.ssh` directory disappears.

So the question is: is there any way to create permanent public key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku manages access control to all of the server instances.

When you run `heroku run bash` it's spinning up a new dyno, SSHing into it, and executing bash on that server.  When you log out, that dyno goes away.

You should rely on Heroku for your access control.  You might be able to configure .ssh keys using a custom Heroku buildpack, but there's still no way to connect directly other than through the Heroku app (since they manage what dynos are running and how to connect to them).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to store keys outside the Heroku application: generate keys and store it in an environment variable which can be added with:

```
heroku config:add ENV_VAR_NAME=value
```

Comment: I know it's been a few years since this was asked but it's still an open question, but: how would one set env vars so that the instance has an `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` file in an `.ssh` dir that utilities can find...?